# How to avoid invalid identifier in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to create a view but I obtain this error "Invalid Identifier".  The problem is  that I try to access a colum name that doesn't exist but I need to have in my view (if the column not exist I need to put null). This is my code sql:

```
select .......
case 
when
   when exists (select 1  from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'Student' and COLUMN_NAME = 'email') then nvl(SUBSTR(student.email, 0, 100),'') else ''
end as STUDENT_EMAIL,
```

This is throwed "`invalid identifier`". I need to create this view and create the field "email" and if exist the colum I must insert the correct otherwise I put in the field value null;

Comment: Why do you not know whether your table contains this column or not?

Comment: @CaiusJard because I don't create table and I must return some result that they aren't in this this table. So I need to check if exist or not

Comment: Then just look at the table definition. You can only create a view on a table and columns that exist.

Comment: What I mean is, are you trying to create a single script that will work on two different customer databases, one of which does have this column and the other of which doesn’t have it? I need to know whether you’re really trying to work with two tables that have different definitions, or whether you’re just trying to work with a table that might not have a value in a column, but the column is always there

Comment: @CaiusJard i'm tring to create a single script that will work on two different customer databases ,one of which does have this column and the other of which doesn’t have it

Comment: I was hoping you wouldn't say that :)

Comment: @CaiusJard I know It is ridiculus, but 4-5 field I need to check if column exists for now,

Comment: Dynamic SQL is your friend here

Answer (score 5):

Use dynamic SQL and try to compile the view and if there are errors then use `NULL` instead:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE students ( id, name )
AS SELECT 1, 'Alice' FROM DUAL;
```

**Create View**:

```
DECLARE
  invalid_identifier EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( invalid_identifier, -904);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE VIEW student_view AS SELECT id, name, SUBSTR( email, 1, 100 ) AS STUDENT_EMAIL FROM students';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN invalid_identifier THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE VIEW student_view AS SELECT id, name, CAST( null AS VARCHAR2(100) ) AS STUDENT_EMAIL FROM students';
END;
/
```

**Results**:

```
SELECT * FROM student_view;
```

```
ID | NAME  | STUDENT_EMAIL
-: | :---- | :------------
 1 | Alice | null
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ab5fa33c48d285bcff77f69c617a7494)*

Answer (score 0):

There is a hacky -- but clever -- way of doing this without using dynamic SQL.

You can use the scoping rules for subqueries to assign an `email` column *if it exists*.  The challenge is that you need to provide a default and you need a primary key:

```
select . . .,  -- all columns from `s` *except* for email
       (select email  -- no qualification
        from students s2
        where s2.id = s.id
       ) as email 
from student s cross join
     (select '' as email from dual
     ) e;
```

If `email` is in `students`, then `select email` chooses that value.  If `email` is not, then it is chosen from `e`.